# Android canvas touch position after scrolling canvas

Tags: android, canvas, calendar

I have designed an android calendar application. When I draw events in canvas, I calculate event position according to time.

[this is image before scrolling](https://www.box.com/s/725e88ba0f0f34b0114c)

[this is image after scrolling](https://www.box.com/s/15ad191e201d12dd90d7)

My problem is, after scrolling. When  I try to get touch position, it gives point with respect to currently showing screen origin.
But I need to get exact point where I draw events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getScrollX() and getScrollY() and add it to event position as offset.